# Gitlab and Terraform state file: why do I have two state file and why does it not modify the default one?

Tags: terraform, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, terraform-state

Here is my simplified `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
include:
 - template: Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.yml  

variables:
 GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN: "$GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN"
 TF_STATE_NAME: "default"

stages:
 - validate
 - build
 - deploy
 - cleanup

before_script:
 - echo "${TF_STATE_NAME}"
 - echo "${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
 - terraform init -reconfigure -backend-config="address=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXXXX/terraform/state/${TF_STATE_NAME}" -backend-config="lock_address=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXXXX/terraform/state/${TF_STATE_NAME}/lock" -backend-config="unlock_address=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXXXX/terraform/state/${TF_STATE_NAME}/lock" -backend-config="username=louisvgn" -backend-config="password=${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}" -backend-config="lock_method=POST" -backend-config="unlock_method=DELETE" -backend-config="retry_wait_min=5"

fmt:
 extends: .terraform:fmt
 needs: []

validate:
 extends: .terraform:validate
 needs: []

build:
 extends: .terraform:build

deploy:
 extends: .terraform:deploy
 script:
  - echo "${TF_STATE_NAME}"
  - echo "${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
 rules:
   - if: $CI_COMMIT_TITLE != "destroy"
     when: on_success
 dependencies:
   - build
 environment:
   name: $TF_STATE_NAME

cleanup:
 extends: .terraform:destroy
 environment:
   name: $TF_STATE_NAME
 rules:
   - if: $CI_COMMIT_TITLE == "destroy"
     when: on_success
```

In the gitlab runners’ logs, the `echo "${TF_STATE_NAME}"` gives me `default` which is expected. However, when I go to `Operate` → `Terraform states` I have the following:

[image]

And I can see that it is the one with the weird `$TF_STATE_NAME` name getting updated and not the `default` one. Why is that? I do not know how the former `$TF_STATE_NAME` appeared… I miss input, probably.

Also, where can we see the versions of a state file in gitlab? I don’t see many options here.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you've included that `before_script` with the `terraform init` command? You shouldn't need to do that; the templated terraform scripts use `gitlab-terraform` which automatically does the correct config for you. I would remove that line in `before_script:` calling `terraform init` and see if that helps.

Comment: If you've hardcoded your backend configuration, remove that, too. You should use an empty `backend http` block only, as described in the [gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/iac/terraform_state.html#initialize-a-terraform-state-as-a-backend-by-using-gitlab-cicd). If you've tried to define this in your HCL using something like `$TF_STATE_NAME` you're probably defining this with the **literal** state name of `$TF_STATE_NAME` for the address rather than properly interpolating the variable.

Comment: Ok makes sense… So I can remove the `$TF_STATE_NAME`? The reason why I added the before script was for the `post-configuration` job in order to have the proper configuration because it was changing from the two terraform state files I had in gitlab… But, yes, it was just messing everything up